# How do I return all values from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, delphi, stored-procedures

Forgive my naivety, but I am new to using Delphi with databases (which may seem odd to some).

I have setup a connection to my database (MSSQL) using a TADOConnection. I am using TADOStoredProc to access my stored procedure.

My stored procedure returns 2 columns, a column full of server names, and a 2nd column full of users on the server. It typically returns about 70 records...not a lot of data.

How do I enumerate this stored procedure programmatically? I am able to drop a DBGrid on my form and attach it to a TDataSource (which is then attached to my ADOStoredProc) and I can verify that the data is correctly being retrieved.

Ideally, I'd like to enumerate the returned data and move it into a TStringList.

Currently, I am using the following code to enumerate the ADOStoredProc, but it only returns '@RETURN_VALUE':

```
ADOStoredProc1.Open;
ADOStoredProc1.ExecProc;
ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.Refresh;

for i := 0 to AdoStoredProc1.Parameters.Count - 1 do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AdoStoredProc1.Parameters.Items[i].Name);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AdoStoredProc1.Parameters.Items[i].Value);
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call Open to get a dataset returned

```
StoredProc.Open;
while not StoredProc.EOF do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(StoredProc.FieldByName('xyz').Value);
  StoredProc.Next;
end;
```

Comment: Don't use a FieldByName inside the loop!
Either have fields defined at design time or create a Field object between the Open and the while loop.

Comment: I expressly selected that route for clarity. But in the post, he was referring to two columns and 70 rows so it's not a large overhead even if you did it this way.  However, I never use fields defined at design time or create a field object as you suggest.  If you want to minimize overhead, you can reference fields by ordinal position which is my preference over defined fields.

Answer (score 3):

Use Open to get the records from the StoredProc
Use either design-time Fields, ad-hoc Fields grabbed with FieldByName before the loop or Fields[nn] to get the values.

```
procedure GetADOResults(AStoredProc: TADOStoredProc; AStrings: TStrings);
var
  fldServer, fldUser: TField;
begin
  AStoredProc.Open;
  fldServer := AStoredProc.FieldByName('ServerName');
  fldUser := AStoredProc.FieldByName('User');
  while not AStoredProc.EOF do
  begin
    AStrings.Add(Format('Server: %s - / User: %s',[fldServer.AsString, fldUser.AsString]));
    // or with FFields and Index (asumming ServerName is the 1st and User the 2nd) and no local vars
    AStrings.Add(Format('Server: %s - / User: %s',[AStoredProc.Fields[0].AsString, AStoredProc.Fields[1].AsString]));
    AStoredProc.Next;
  end;
end;


//use like
  GetADOResults(ADOStoredProc1, Memo1.Lines);
```

Note: Fields[nn] allows to write less code but beware if the StoredProc changes the order of the returned columns.

Answer (score 2):

If your stored procedure returns a result set (rows of data), don't use ExecProc. It's designed to execute procedures with no result set. Use Open or Active instead, and then you can process them just as you are using Parameters:

```
ADOStoredProc.Open;

for i := 0 to ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.Count - 1 do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.Items[i].Name);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ADOStoredProc1.Parameters.Items[i].Value);
end;
```

BTW, calling Open and then ExecProc causes problems; Open returns a result set, ExecProc then clears it because you're running the procedure a second time with no result set expected. I also don't think you need the Parameters.Refresh, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: Does it matter if the SP returns a result set when the code loops through the Parameters collection?  i.e. won't this code return the same result as the OP's? (disclaimer: I'm not a Delphi programmer, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the question...)

Comment: Of course it matters. The OP was getting a resultset with Open, and then discarding it with ExecSQL, leaving nothing to loop through. Removing the ExecSQL and using Open (or Active := True) leaves a resultset to iterate. IOW, it's not the same result as the OP's. :-)

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding, the OP wants the RECORDS not the parameters. He basically wants to get programmatically what's returned in the DBGrid.

Comment: Read the Delphi docs on AdoStoredProcedure. The result set is RETURNED in the parameters. Also tested myself; you might do the same. :-)

Comment: Ah, I see.  The code looks like something I should be able to read (if not write), but I didn't expect a result set returned in the parameters. ;-)  Thanks, Ken.

Comment: @Matt: You're welcome. :-) And the comment about "testing yourself" wasn't addressed to you, but @François, just for the record. <g>

Comment: @Ken: What are you talking about? The results (i.e. out params if any) are returned in the parameters but not the data records (which is what is needed here). They are returned in 1 or more recordset(s) that you can access with the Fields objects as seen in the accepted answer (and in my answer as well).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this (just Googled it):

```
[http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesDelphi12&Lang=EN#Procedure][1]
```

Basically, a SQL Server stored procedure always returns one return value, but it can also create a result set, which you need to process like the data set returned from a regular select statement.